# Creating a new Web User Control .ascx file in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac, ascx

I have Visual Studio for Mac 8.3.3

I was a little disappointed finding out that you cannot [open a folder in VS for Mac](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/459820/cant-open-folder-in-vs2019.html).

I'm going through a basic tutorial, and the first step is to create a new .ascx file, Web User Control C#.  I'm unable to figure out how to do this.  The interface seems to look like this in the older windows version, Visual Studio Community 2017.

[image]

I do not see `Web User Control` in File > New File

If this is done correctly, the file seems to contain `<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile... etc.`

[image]

---

UPDATE:

So I figured out how to access parent folder and create a file:

1. Under Solution, right click on (master) > Display Options > Show All Files
2. Navigate to the folder of choice, right click on the folder > Add > New File
3. C# > ASP.NET Web Forms > User Control
4. Type name, `HelloWorld.ascx`

This still doesn't have the expected result though.
With the new file open, if I save to the directory then I can see that the .ascx file is generated, but I am unable to navigate within to `HelloWorld.ascx.cs` like pictured above.